# concourse pipeline - throwing error for sub folders "not a valid repository name"

Tags: concourse, concourse-git-resource, concourse-pipeline, concourse-task, concourse-resource-types

I have repository which has two frontend application and one server folder. i need to create pipeline for two frontend(angular) and one server(nodejs) folder. if I create a pipeline for main folder(concourse-pipeline) its working fine. but when I try to create to pipeline for subfolders(frontend) its throwing an error as "not a valid repository name". I'm not sure whats going wrong here.

```
  - name: repo
    type: git
    source:
      uri: git@github.com:test-repo/concourse-pipeline.git
      branch: master
      private_key: ((repo.private-key))

  - name: frontend
    type: git
    source:
      uri: git@github.com:test-repo/concourse-pipeline/frontend.git
      branch: master
      private_key: ((repo.private-key))

  - name: version
    type: semver
    source:
      driver: git
      initial_version: 0.0.1
      uri: git@github.com:test-repo/concourse-pipeline.git
      private_key: ((repo.private-key))
      branch: master
      file: version

  - name: run-server
    type: git
    source:
      uri: git@github.com:test-repo/concourse-pipeline.git
      branch: master
      private_key: ((repo.private-key))

jobs:
  - name: run-server
    build_logs_to_retain: 20
    max_in_flight: 1
    plan:
      - get: run-server
        trigger: true
      - task: run-tests
        config:
          platform: linux
          image_resource:
            type: registry-image
            source:
              repository: node
          inputs:
            - name: run-server
          run:
            path: /bin/sh
            args:
              - -c
              - |
                echo "Node Version: $(node --version)"
                echo "NPM Version: $(npm --version)"
                cd run-server
                npm install
                npm test

  - name: run-frontend
    build_logs_to_retain: 20
    max_in_flight: 1
    plan:
      - get: frontend
        trigger: true
      - task: run-tests
        config:
          platform: linux
          image_resource:
            type: registry-image
            source:
              repository: node
          inputs:
            - name: frontend
          run:
            path: /bin/sh
            args:
              - -c
              - |
                echo "Node Version: $(node --version)"
                echo "NPM Version: $(npm --version)"
                cd frontend
                npm install
                ng test

  - name: bump-version
    plan:
      - get: repo
        trigger: true
      - put: version
        params:
          bump: patch

  - name: build-repo
    plan:
      - get: repo
        trigger: true
      - get: version
        params:
          build: repo
          tag_file: version/version
          tag_as_latest: true
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The `uri` of the `frontend` resource seems invalid.

```
uri: git@github.com:test-repo/concourse-pipeline/frontend.git
```

The Github address should be only `git@github.com:(user):(repository).git`